# Visual Studio for Mac doesn't have any "Office add-in" project

Tags: macos, visual-studio, outlook, outlook-addin, office-js

I have done some digging and can see that Visual Studio for Mac should offer a way to create "Office add-in" projects which will be based on Office-JS API (JavaScript) instead of the .Net COM technology.

However, in Visual Studio for Mac 7.0.1 -> New Project, I cannot see any add-in or Office option. I am using Community version so that could be the problem. But before I can upgrade to Enterprise or Professional, I need to be sure that has the Office add-in option.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Hisham.

Comment: I'm researching, but I'm pretty sure that the Office Web Add-in templates are not supported in any version of VS for Mac. I'll report here what I find and what workarounds if any.

Comment: I have confirmed that VS for Mac does not support templates. That applies to the Prof and Enterprise versions as well. See Kim's answer for a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **Yeoman generator** to create an Office Add-in on Mac. It'll automatically create the project scaffolding for you, and then you can use the editor of your choice (including Visual Studio for Mac) to modify the code for your add-in. Check out these resources for detailed info about creating an Office Web Add-in using Yeoman generator:

- https://dev.office.com/blogs/creating-office-add-ins-with-any-editor-introducing-yo-office
- https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/get-started/create-an-office-add-in-using-any-editor

(I don't personally know whether or not any version of Visual Studio for Mac offers built-in support for creating Office Web Add-ins; I'll do some digging and update my answer here if I'm able to find definitive info on that.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I could've sworn I came across a VS for Mac tutorial for Office add-ins which led me to believe my VS didn't have that option. Maybe I got confused following a tutorial that referred to Mac but used screenshots from VS Windows. Anyway, I'm marking your reply as the valid one for now and feel free to update it later.

Comment: Happy I could help. I'm still seeking out definitive info about built-in support for creating Office Web Add-ins in Visual Studio for Mac, and will certainly update this thread if/when I get a definitive answer one way or the another.